# convert file to Xml in android

Tags: android

Hello
I am using Android 1.5.
I am using database to save the user details.My requirement is like if two users want something to share between then the data in the database should be converted to XML file and sent to the server.
Is there any way that i can achieve this in android.
Is there anything like plist in iphone for android as well.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send XML data to server you can convert it into XML string form and post it to server.

There are java codes available for posting data to server.

If you want to parse the returned XML, two types of parsing techniques are there,

- DOM PArsing
- SAX Parsing

This is how you can post XML string:

```
String xmlDataToSend="your xml string";
URL url = new URL(remote Server Url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(remote Server Url);
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value by which you capture data on server",xmlDataToBeSent)); 


httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                           
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


//================   get response


HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String line=null;
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
    sb.append(line+"\n");


Log.i("returned xml",sb.toString());
```

Hope that helps
Thanks

Comment: Thanks VIV.Can you just provide some sample code as how can i post data to the server.

Comment: Thanks Viv for quick response.

Comment: my pleasure hope it helped you.